# Object Creation with spread arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a new array of objects with a nested for loop. I am calling the `Object.assign` method with a spread argument to create a new object, but I think the problem lies with there being the same object key for each item and I only get an output with the last item in the loop. Here is the code:

```
let array1 = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
let array2 = [
  [1, "a", "b", "c"],
  [2, "d", "e", "f"],
  [3, "g", "h", "i"],
  [4, "j", "k", "l"],
  [5, "m", "n", "o"]
];

let matchedVals = [];
let finalVals = [];

for (let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    matchedVals.push({ [array2[i]]: array1[j][i] })
    finalVals.push(Object.assign(...matchedVals))
  }
}


//End Result Expected
// [
//   {
//     "first": 1,
//     "second": "a",
//     "third": "b",
//     "forth": "c"
//   }, {
//     "first": 2,
//     "second": "d",
//     "third": "e",
//     "forth": "f"
//   }, {
//     "first": 3,
//     "second": "g",
//     "third": "e",
//     "forth": "h"
//   }

//   ...

// ]
```

I am sure there is something simple, but I am not familiar enough with Object.Assign to understand what I can do to get around this issue.

Comment: you're running Object.assign for every iteration of i, which looks wrong - also, Object.assign expects one target and one or more sources - what is your target?

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: I think you mixed up the two arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Object.assign` here at all. Creating objects with single properties just to merge them together seems wasteful. Why not mutate a single object (per top level array element)?

I would use `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` or a plain old loop:

```js
let array1 = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
let array2 = [
  [1, "a", "b", "c"],
  [2, "d", "e", "f"],
  [3, "g", "h", "i"],
  [4, "j", "k", "l"],
  [5, "m", "n", "o"]
];


const finalResult = array2.map(
  values => values.reduce((obj, val, i) => (obj[array1[i]] = val, obj), {})
);
console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: Nice, concise answer!

Answer (score 1):

The main issues with your code is the order of the for loops, which array you are using which index on, and your misuse of Object.assign

compare your for loops

```
for (let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        matchedVals.push({ [array2[i]]: array1[j][i] })
        finalVals.push(Object.assign(...matchedVals))
    }
}
```

with this

```
for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    let matchedVals = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        matchedVals.push({ [array1[j]]: array2[i][j] })
    }
    finalVals.push(Object.assign({},...matchedVals))
}
```

However, @FelixKling's answer is better code - I just wanted you to see where your code went wrong

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes in my code. After staring at it for a while, I just couldn't get it!

Comment: Sometimes having names like `array1`, `array2`, and `i`, `j` can be blinding :p